# Azure Cosmos DB - StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to insert a clan entity to Clan container. My partition key is **id** and the model is like this:

```
public class Clan
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ClanName { get; set; }
    public int MembersCount { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public int WHP { get; set; }
    public int LogoId { get; set; }
    public AppMarketType AppMarket { get; set; }
}
```

ClanDbContext:

```
public class ClanContext : DbContext
{
    public ClanContext(DbContextOptions<ClanContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Clan> Clans { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Clan>()
            .HasNoDiscriminator()
            .ToContainer("Clans")
            .HasPartitionKey(p => p.Id)
            .Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");
    }
}
```

All I want to do is:

```
try
{
    var clan = new Clan
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        AppMarket = Core.AppMarketType.GooglePlay,
        ClanName = "Blazers",
        Capacity = 110,
        LogoId = 342,
        MembersCount = 34,
        WHP = 1280
    };
    _clanContext.Add(clan);
    _clanContext.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     throw;
 }
```

It throws an exception:

**StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')**

Callstack:

```
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Remove(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.ValueGeneration.Internal.IdValueGenerator.NextValue(EntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator.Next(EntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ValueGenerationManager.Generate(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
at Dummy.Web.Services.ClanService.<IncreaseWHP>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Repositories\dummysolution\Domain\dummydomain\Services\ClanService.cs:line 50
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Clans.JoinGroup.<Run>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Repositories\dummysolution\API\dummyapi\Clans\JoinGroup.cs:line 55
```

Comment: Pleas add callstack to the question.

Comment: Cosmos DB doesn't evaluate the JsonProperty attribute. Pls check it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I added the callstack.

Comment: @JasonPan When I don't provide the attribute, it throws exception. What do you mean by saying "doesn't evaluate"?

Comment: @Orhun Please show us the code around `JoinGroup.cs:line 55`.

Comment: @JasonPan It corresponds to catch(Exception) line from the code I shared.

Comment: @Orhun Pls [check this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21396#issuecomment-648561563), and you can try to not configure the partition key. Hope it useful to you.

Comment: Pls add `ID` in PartitionKey area. It seems you don't configure it.

Comment: @JasonPan I configured it in OnModelCreating method like this: .HasPartitionKey(p => p.Id). Is there something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242053/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-orhun).

Answer (score 0):

After confirm with contributor, this issue was fixed in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 5.0.0`.

If you are using a version before 5.0.0, please try after upgrading.

If you are getting a similar exception in 5.0.0 or later please file a new issue and include a small project that demonstrates it.

---

Related Issue:

[Cannot create new item in collection](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21957)